# Oracle 12c - Create materialized view results in ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, materialized-view, dblink, synonyms

I have a view that I can access through a database link as such:

```
SQL> select count(*) from REMOTE_SCHEMA.REMOTE_VIEW@REMOTE_DB;

COUNT(*)
--------
110
```

I can create and successfully query the remote view through a synonym:

```
SQL> create synonym REMOTE_VIEW for REMOTE_SCHEMA.REMOTE_VIEW@REMOTE_DB;

Synonym created

SQL> select count(*) from REMOTE_VIEW;

COUNT(*)
--------
110
```

If I try to create a materialized view using the synonym however, it fails:

```
SQL> create materialized view REMOTE_MV
build immediate
refresh complete
next sysdate+1
with ROWID
as
select * from REMOTE_VIEW;

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Creating the materialized view without the synonym succeeds:

```
SQL> create materialized view REMOTE_MV
build immediate
refresh complete
next sysdate+1
with ROWID
as
select * from REMOTE_SCHEMA.REMOTE_VIEW@REMOTE_DB;

Materialized view created
```

Any ideas why using the synonym fails? Ideally I would like to use the synonym to insulate the materialized view from the database link. The database link could differ based on environment and I want to ensure the materialized view query remains the same regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure it out! You **can** create materialized views on synonyms, however it was my lack of understanding edition-based redefinition (EBR) that was causing the issues.

Private synonyms by default are EDITIONABLE:

> [CREATE SYNONYM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401)
>
> [ EDITIONABLE | NONEDITIONABLE ]
>
> Use these clauses to specify whether the synonym is an editioned or noneditioned object if editioning is enabled for the schema object type SYNONYM in schema. **For private synonyms, the default is EDITIONABLE**. For public synonyms, the default is NONEDITIONABLE.

Materialized views however are noneditioned objects:

> [Using Edition-Based Redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020)
>
> 24.1.1.2.1 Materialized Views
>
> A materialized view is a noneditioned object that can specify an evaluation edition, thereby enabling it to depend on editioned objects.
>
> > CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW [ schema.] materialized_view other_clauses
> >     [ evaluation_edition_clause ] [ query_rewrite_clause ] AS subquery
> >
> > Where evaluation_edition_clause is:
> >
> > EVALUATE USING { CURRENT EDITION | EDITION edition | NULL EDITION }
>
> CURRENT EDITION is the edition in which the DDL statement runs. Specifying NULL EDITION is equivalent to omitting the clause that includes it. **If you omit evaluation_edition_clause, then editioned objects are invisible during name resolution.**

So I successfully tested two options to solve the problem:

- Option 1 - make the synonym NONEDITIONABLE, in which case it will be visible to the materialized view OR
- Option 2 - Specify the evaluation_edition_clause on the materialized view.

Answer (score 2):

> Use the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement to create a materialized view. A materialized view is a database object that contains the results of a query. The FROM clause of the query can name tables, views, and other materialized views.
>   [More](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)

You cannot create Materialized View from Synonym. I don't know why would you like to that but we create materialized view as your working example.